# Warning when using function pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, compiler-warnings

This is actually a non-critical question, but I get this warning most of the time I use function pointers and still couldn't figure out why on my own. Consider the following prototype:

```
typedef void * Pointer;
void tree_destroyLineage(Tree greatest_parent, void *dataDestructor(Pointer data));
```

And so far I can compile my thousand-line-long code and get zero warnings. So I'm assuming I wrote the declaration correctly. But then I call it in code, passing free as my destructor, since the data stored in the tree nodes are simple structs:

```
tree_destroyLineage(decision_tree, free);
```

And this makes me get a `"warning: passing argument 2 of 'tree_destroyLineage' from incompatible pointer type"` message. My first hypotesis was that the compiler couldn't figure out at compile time that `Pointer` and `void *` are the same thing, so I tried both creating another function with the exact same types of the function pointer that "repasses" the call to `free()` and changing the function pointer declaration to accept a `void *` instead of a Pointer. Both approaches gave me the very same warning at the very same place.

What am I doing wrong and how do I solve it?

Comment: Your use of a typedef for a pointer is really stupid. Just use void *.

Comment: I've been told that lots of times... still haven't changed it because I would have to change lots of existing code using time I don't really have. Also, some evaluators are a little resistant to the use of void *s, so I'm just removing the 'transparency'.

Also, GLIB's "gpointer" type is exactly the same thing, a typedef to void *. Actually, it goes on even further and defines "gconstpointer" for "const void *". Also, at least as my tests indicate, this wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why so mean? I don't find it stupid... You conceal the fact that pointers are implemented as `void *`, and approximates the code to natural language.

Comment: It's just extra typing, and makes the code confusing. Any C programmer would understand void *, but they would have to look up Pointer to understand it. It does make the code closer to natural language, but code is not meant to be read out loud.

Comment: I agree it's extra typing, but there's no sense in calling people stupid for their coding style preferences.

Comment: @Beau: yes, that was the original idea.
@Zfire: I think that Pointer is easily understood as a "generic pointer", and so do the people that have read my code. I agree with you that, had I been coding this from the ground up today, I would have used void * instead. But you should also agree that there good arguments for both sides. For the third time, the mere fact that GLIB uses that is an indicator of that.

Comment: You may also just use "void tree_destroyLineage(Tree greatest_parent, void dataDestructor(Pointer data));" just get rid of the star

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across as being overly harsh for criticizing you, I probably chose the wrong words.

Comment: Thanks, this is very nice of you. However, the tone was not my problem, but the dogmatic statement. =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the correct signature for a function like free is:

```
void (*freefunc)(void*)
```

not

```
void *dataDestructor(Pointer data)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves it even if I keep using Pointer instead of "void *". After JF's post I realized what was going wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about your library, but my free has no return value (i.e., it's void).  It doesn't return a void pointer.

If you want the 2nd argument to be a pointer to a function which returns void and takes as an argument a void pointer, I believe what you want is:

void (*fn)(void*)

and not

void *fn(void*)

which is what you have.

Comment: Thanks, this made me see the difference. My destructor function was being declared as void * instead of void, and this was causing the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
void tree_destroyLineage(Tree greatest_parent, 
                          void *dataDestructor(Pointer data));
```

should be:

```
void tree_destroyLineage(Tree greatest_parent, 
                          void (*dataDestructor)(Pointer data));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void tree_destroyLineage(Tree greatest_parent, void (*dataDestructor)(void *data));
```

Using a `typedef` for a void pointer is just plain silly.

Edit: the problem is that, without the parenthesis around `*dataDestructor`, the compiler thinks that the function returns `void *`, rather than `void`. The parenthesis tell the compiler that the function returns `void`, but is a pointer to a function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As I told in my reply comment in my original post, I got the idea of "typedeffing" void * from GLIB (GTK+ 'base' library) when I was building my custom "generic" containers library. So, you can blame them and call them silly. =)

Comment: Yes, I consider GLib silly too :). The whole idea of GLib is flawed. They are basically trying to write C++ in C.

Comment: Sure "simulating" functionalities of a more recent language in an older one is anti-logical, so I've been told, but GLIB does its job very well. And time is a serious matter when you have the constraint to use only pure C and you are spending your time implementing a thousand of list types while you should really be focusing on what your hybrid-greedy-bruteforce algorithms does with all the trees it creates.

Comment: I think some of GLib is silly (e.g. gchar is always exactly equivalent to char), but other parts are very useful (like GHashTable).